# How to understand Abel's sentence

Tags: math-history

How to understand this paragraph from chapter 9 of《Encounter with mathematics》?

from Abel's paper.

`"The divergent series may sometimes successfully serve as symbols of certain
abridged propositions, but they should not take the place of determined quantities.
By such procedures we can prove all we want, the possible as well as the
impossible".`

Are there some certain propositions?

Comment: I found the following quote as well “Divergent series are the invention of the devil, and it is shameful to base on them any demonstration
whatsoever.”—N. H. Abel

Comment: This link may help you understand why he said that:  http://math.arizona.edu/~cais/Papers/Expos/div.pdf

Comment: Try searching this site for Abel summation.

Comment: See [Divergent series : History](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divergent_series#History) : "Before the 19th century, divergent series were widely used by Leonhard Euler and others, but often led to confusing and contradictory results. A major problem was Euler's idea that any divergent series should have a natural sum, without first defining what is meant by the sum of a divergent series." Consider e.g. $1-1+1-\ldots$; the point of Abel's statement is : we cannot ask "what is $1-1+1-\ldots$ ?" because it is not a "quantity".

Comment: It may have been widely used by Euler, but it did not *often* lead to confusing and contradictory results. Perhaps once in all of his 4 meters of collected works.